# Stylus is not working with React

Tags: css, reactjs, web-applications, stylus

I'm helping create a webapp and we've recently switched to stylus and react. I've rewritten all the stylus lang files and written some react but the react is not being styled at all. Here is the component below.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Icon from 'react-component-bytesize-icons'

class CoursesCard extends Component {
    render() {
        const divStyle = {
            backgroundImage : '/assets/img/animatingCourse.jpg'
        }

        return (
          <div className='CoursesCard' style={divStyle}>
            <div className='CardOverlay'>
              <h3>What the courses is called?</h3>
              <p>Last Checed</p>
              <p>Users online</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default CoursesCard
```

Here is the stylus lang code:

```
 .CoursesCard {
   width 32%
   margin 10px 1%
   float left
   padding-top 20%
   display inline-block
   background white
   box-shadow 0px 3px 20px #555

   background-repeat no-repeat
   background-size cover
   cursor pointer

   &.hover{
      box-shadow 0px 3px 22px #333
    }

.CardOverlay {
    width 100%
   height auto
   padding 10px 0
   background rgba(33,51,66,0.8)
   color #fff

   background-repeat no-repeat
   background-size cover
   cursor pointer

  &.hover {
    box-shadow 0px 3px 22px #333
  }

  h3{
    font-size 18px
    font-weight 500
      margin-bottom 5px
    margin-left 10px
  }
  p.lastChecked{
    font-size 13px
      font-weight 100
      margin-bottom 5px
      margin-left 10px
  }
  p.onlineUsers{
    font-size 14px
      font-weight 400
      margin-left 10px
      display block
  }
}
```

}

Comment: check my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52111496/how-to-configure-stylus-support-in-a-react-js-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React has nothing to do with Stylus at all.

I suppose you are using Webpack as bundler of choice. If so, you have to configure Webpack so that it understands what to do with `.styl` files (or whatever file extension is used).

Webpack has concept of **loaders** - loader loads file, transforms it in some way and pushes output down the chain.

You need to add **stylus loader**. To do so, please take a look at this plugin's [GH page](https://github.com/shama/stylus-loader)

Answer (score 3):

Using Stylus in React requires a bundler like Webpack. I use Stylus + React a lot, so I can help but your question doesn't tell me if you have Webpack and npm or yarn set up.

Since I don't see your full build, I can share my build and maybe that will help. This is the closest I can get to helping you step-by-step without knowing more about your current build. Hope this helps!

Assuming you have Webpack and npm set up and your project has a package.json file already...

1. Run these commands in terminal...

`npm install yarn`

`yarn init`

```
yarn add poststylus autoprefixer-stylus autoprefixer
```

css-loader poststylus sass-loader style-loader stylus-loader

2. Make your webpack.config.js similar to this...

   ```
   const path = require('path');
   const postStylus = require('poststylus');
   const webpack = require('webpack');

   module.exports = {
     context: __dirname,
     entry: [
       './source/ClientApp.jsx',
       'react-hot-loader/patch',
       'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080/',
       'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
     ],
     devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
     output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
       filename: 'bundle.js',
       publicPath: '/public/',
       hotUpdateChunkFilename: 'hot/hot-update.js',
       hotUpdateMainFilename: 'hot/hot-update.json'
     },
     devServer: {
       hot: true,
       publicPath: '/public/',
       historyApiFallback: true,
     },
     watch: true,
     plugins: [
       new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
       new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
       // new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
          options: {
           stylus: {
             preferPathResolver: 'webpack',
           },
          }
        }),
     ],
     resolve: {
       extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.styl'],
       modules: [
         path.resolve('./source'),
         path.resolve('./node_modules'),
       ],
     },
     stats: {
       colors: true,
       reasons: true,
       chunks: true,
     },
     module: {
       rules: [
         {
           enforce: 'pre',
           test: /\.js$/,
           loader: 'eslint-loader',
           exclude: /node_modules/,
         },
         {
           test: /\.jsx?$/,
           loader: 'babel-loader',
         },
         {
           test: /\.styl$/,
           use: [
             'style-loader',
             'css-loader',
             {
               loader: 'stylus-loader',
               options: {
                 use: [
                   postStylus(['autoprefixer']),
                 ],
                 modules: true,
               },
             },
           ],
           exclude: /node_modules/,
         },
       ],
     },
   };
   ```
3. And here is my entire package.json if you need it for reference...

   ```
   {
     "scripts": {
       "lint": "eslint **/*.{js,jsx} --quiet",
       "clean": "rm -r public/bundle.js",
       "build": "rm -r public/bundle.js && webpack",
       "dev": "webpack-dev-server --watch --progress --colors",
       "watch": "webpack --watch"
     },
     "dependencies": {
       "autoprefixer": "^7.1.2",
       "autoprefixer-stylus": "^0.14.0",
       "axios": "^0.16.2",
       "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
       "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
       "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
       "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.0.2",
       "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.0.1",
       "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
       "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
       "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
       "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
       "babel-preset-airbnb": "^2.4.0",
       "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
       "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
       "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
       "concurrently": "^3.5.0",
       "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
       "d3": "^4.10.0",
       "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
       "eslint": "3.19.0",
       "eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.0.2",
       "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^11.2.0",
       "eslint-config-react": "^1.1.7",
       "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
       "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
       "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.0.3",
       "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.1.0",
       "express": "^4.15.3",
       "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
       "firebase": "^4.2.0",
       "firebase-tools": "^3.9.2",
       "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
       "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
       "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
       "poststylus": "^0.2.3",
       "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
       "react": "^15.6.1",
       "react-date-range": "^0.9.4",
       "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
       "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.6",
       "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
       "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1",
       "resolve-url-loader": "^2.1.0",
       "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
       "sort-package-json": "^1.7.0",
       "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
       "stylus": "^0.54.5",
       "stylus-loader": "^3.0.1",
       "webpack": "2.6.1",
       "webpack-combine-loaders": "^2.0.3",
       "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.11.0",
       "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1",
       "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.18.2"
     },
   }
   ```